# Set up a cron every hour

Tags: cron, cpanel

I try to set up a cron on my cpanel.
I want to execute that cron every hour

```
ex.: 1:00,2:00 ,3:00....23:00,24:00
```

How can I do that?Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this a programming task? It soundsmore like a configuration issue...

Answer (score 4):

Usually the structure is like this

```
0 * * * *
```

anf if you are trying to acces a link

```
0 * * * * wget http://example.com/file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

/5 means you run something every 5:th (hour minute or similar). Try /1.

Comment: * * * * * = every minute of every hour of every day.
* /1 * * * practically means the same but will adapt to your other cron syntax set and will be read as an interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
@hourly your_command
```

[Source](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/cron)