# How to run python script from Linux terminal every hour?

Tags: python, linux

So I want to run this command **python run.py** from the linux terminal every hour. 
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: did you look into cron?

Comment: cron .e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340358/set-up-a-cron-every-hour

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/139401/making-a-command-run-once-every-hour

Comment: Do you really need that script to be run in a *terminal* (read [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) to understand how *complex* a "terminal" is), or do you just want that script to be run every hour (*without* a terminal)? Please **edit your question to improve it** and motivate it (what is `run.py` doing, where exactly is it)? You say "*the* linux terminal" but in general you might have *several* (pseudo-)terminals, and you probably don't have any *physical* terminal (à la [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100), in museums...)

Comment: Out of interest why a terminal rather than as a batchjob with a log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command `watch` on unix to run any command any set interval of time.

More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix)

(chose this way over cron because you specified in a terminal, and this would allow you to see the output in the terminal you start it from)

Answer (score 8):

Edit your crontab using 
`crontab -e`
add the following line to run your script every hour

```
0 * * * *  python <path-to-file>
```

you can list scheduled crons using `crontab -l`

Comment: Good, however this wont run the script in a *terminal* but simply in a batch job

Answer (score 4):

The simple way is using the `cron` job, using this command 
`crontab -e` you will see the image below 
[image]

you can add this command to the cron configuration:

```
* */1 * * * python /root/yourprogram.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

the `*/1` is for executing every hour the python program, look the structure of the `cron` command:

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
    0        2          12             *                *            /usr/bin/find
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use **`BlockingScheduler`** from **`apscheduler.schedulers.blocking`**.

Just install it using the command `pip install APScheduler` or `pip3 install APScheduler`. This is good.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def your_job():
    print("Do you job")

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(your_job, 'interval', seconds=5)
scheduler.start()
```

After every 5 seconds,

```
Do you job
Do you job
```

Will be printed. Great thing is you can also specify the `minutes` or `hours` just change the parameter. So in your case just change `seconds=5` to `hours=1`.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
def your_job():
        print("Do you job")

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(your_job, 'interval', hours=1)
scheduler.start()
```